# LLVM: Setting function attributes on a pointer

Tags: code-generation, llvm

In some code I'm generating via the LLVM C++ API, at one point I'm given a raw address to a function. I turn this into a function pointer and call it as follows:

```
llvm::FunctionType* ft = llvm::FunctionType::get(...);
llvm::Constant* iptr = llvm::ConstantInt::get(
    engine->getDataLayout()->getIntPtrType(state.context, 0), (uint64_t) pointer);
llvm::Value* fptr = llvm::ConstantExpr::getIntToPtr(iptr,
    llvm::PointerType::get(ft, 0));

llvm::Value* retval = state.builder.CreateCall(fptr, params);
```

This works fine --- *but* I want to be able to set some function attributes to aid in optimisation: specifically, `readnone`.

Unfortunately the only API I've found to do this is on `llvm::Function`, and I don't have one. I'd expect the attributes to be a property of the function type because that's how it works in C, but `llvm::FunctionType` doesn't seem to have an attributes API on it.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You may annotate the `CallInst` with any function attribute through its `CallInst::addAttribute` API (and similar for `InvokeInst`). This means that you will need to have distinct call sites if you plan to call through one pointer that is `readnone` and one that is not.